# Send a POST request and Open that web page Using C#

Tags: c#, html, post, webclient

I want to send a POST request from my C# code to a web page (which i have created) and open that web page in a browser.

How can i do that?

I saw that following code segment allow me to send a POST request but i do not know how to open it on a web page.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
      var data = new NameValueCollection();
      data["username"] = "myUser";
      data["password"] = "myPassword";

      var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```

Please help

Comment: You mean open in an external browser (like chrome or ie) or does your application have a browsercontrol where you want do display the page?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.. yes i meat in an external browser like Chrome...

Comment: Maybe you could use something like Selenium? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/